# an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: java, mysql

java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error or access violation, message from server:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''list' (fname1,lname1,email1,email,'dob1',str,city,state,zip,order,qua,rate,comm' at line 1"

```
String k="insert into `list` (fname1,lname1,email1,email,'dob1',str,city,state,zip,order,qua,rate,comment,amt) values ('"+fname1+"','"+lname1+"','"+email1+"','"+email+"','"+dob1+"','"+str+"','"+city+"','"+state+"',"+zip+",'"+ord+"',"+qua+","+rating+",'"+comment+"',"+amt+")";
```

[Here the table desc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTQJg.png)

Comment: You need to surround your column values with `'` (and escape any `'` the `String`(s) already contain). **Or** change your code to use `PreparedStatement` and bind parameters.

Comment: **WARNING**: When composing SQL queries it’s important to [properly escape](http://bobby-tables.com/java) any and all user-data to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). This code exposes you to severe risk and should not be deployed.

Answer (score 2):

The error message point 2 single quotes on your string, check if some double quote is not writen as 2 single quotes.

But, to solve it efficiently, its recomended to use PeparedStatement in order to avoid sql injection, and escape of unexpected String, as @Elliott pointed.

Here an example:

```
String k="insert into list (fname1,lname1,email1,email,dob1,str,city,state,zip,order,qua,rate,comment,amt) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(k);
ps.setString(1, fname1);
ps.setString(2, lname1);
...
ps.execute();
ps.close();
conn.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using reserved SQL keyword **order** for your personal use. I could see one of your column name is **order**.

For hibernate xml mapping, I have solved it just by surrounding the order keyword with **`** as following...

```
<property name="order" type="int" column="`order`" not-null="true" />
```

You could also try similar approach in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes around **list** are not required. That's the wrong type of single quote too. And you are also missing a semicolon **;** at the end of your statement and it looks like you forgot to wrap the last value with a single quote. But the error comes because you have a single quote in your field brackets around **'dob1'**

```
String k="insert into list (fname1,lname1,email1,email,dob1,str,city,state,zip,order,qua,rate,comment,amt) values ('"+fname1+"','"+lname1+"','"+email1+"','"+email+"','"+dob1+"','"+str+"','"+city+"','"+state+"',"+zip+",'"+ord+"',"+qua+","+rating+",'"+comment+"','"+amt+"');";
```